# How do i access a specific element in a dictionary?

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json, object

I have a dictionary with one list and 2 dictionaries in the list:

```
dict: {
 "weather":[
   {"id": 701, "main": "Mist", "description": "mist"},
   {"id": 300, "main": "Drizzle", "description": "light intensity drizzle"}
 ]
}
```

I want to access `light intensity drizzle` in the dictionary, how would I do so?

I know I have to do `dict[0]`... but I'm stuck thereafter

Comment: is this a question relating to python or js?

Comment: If this is indeed python, don't use `dict` as a variable name. It's already a builtin, and you'll run into problems at some point if you do.

Comment: If it is JS you can go for a filter, `dict.weather.filter(w=>w.description==='light intensity drizzle')`.

Comment: @ravibagul91 Would that not return the whole `{"id": 300, "main": "Drizzle", "description": "light intensity drizzle"}` object?

Comment: Why do you think you need `dict[0]`? `0` is a list index, not a dictionary key.

Comment: Sounds like you need to review the basics of accessing dictionaries and lists.

Comment: @shash678 yes it will return an object. After that we can get value `result[0].description` if result of filter stored in result variable.

Comment: @ravibagul91 sounds good 

Answer (score 0):

You have a dictionary/map with one key (`"weather"`) that has a value of a list/array, with the second index having the desired description field, index into the dictionary/map appropriately:

**For Python:**

```
d = {
        "weather": [
            {
                "id": 701,
                "main": "Mist",
                "description": "mist"
            },
            {
                "id": 300,
                "main": "Drizzle",
                "description": "light intensity drizzle"
            }
        ]
    }

drizzle_string = d["weather"][1]["description"]
print(drizzle_string)
```

**Output:**

```
light intensity drizzle
```

---

**For Javascript:**

```js
const m = {
             "weather": [
                 {
                     "id": 701,
                     "main": "Mist",
                     "description": "mist"
                 },
                 {
                     "id": 300,
                     "main": "Drizzle",
                     "description": "light intensity drizzle"
                 }
             ]
         }

const drizzle_string = m["weather"][1]["description"]
console.log(drizzle_string)
```

Comment: @jaiyeko Did any answer solve your question? If not how can we help further?

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript:

```
dict.weather[1].description
```

In Python:

```
dictVar["weather"][1]["description"]
```

<sub>(Changing `dict` to `dictVar` is required for Python as `dict` is reserved)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

## Unraveling the problem

You can follow the next logic:

1. You are dealing with a object called *dict*.
2. It has a key called *wheather* that has an array asigned.
3. That array is an array of objects with various keys in each.

## In Javascript

In order to look for the value that is assigned to a key in an object/dictionary in Javascript you have to concatenate the name of the parent, a *dot*, and the name of the key that is nested in the parent:

```
dict.wheather
```

The next step is to get inside the array. To do this you have to put the index inside a square brackets:

```
dict.wheather[1]
```

Note that the first element inside the array has 0 as the index.

Next you repeat the fist step, and write a *dot* and the key that you are looking for.

```
dict.wheather[1].description
```

Then, remember to assign it to a variable and consoleloggit in order to print it.

```
var myVariable = dict.wheather[1].description;
console.log(myVariable);
```

## In Python

You can use the same logic, but you will need to change the key *"dict"* because is a word reserved to python itself. In this case Im showing you the example with *dictionary* instead of *dict*. Also im printing witout assigning the key to a variable.
Also, you will need to change the sintax a little bit:

```
print(dictionary["weather"][1]["description"])
```

Hope it was useful to you :)

For More Resources check these:

- [JS objects in w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_objects.asp)
- [JS Arrays in w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp)
- [Python dictionaries in w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp)
- [Python arrays in w3School](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_arrays.asp)

Sorry if my english inst very good :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dict = {
 "weather":[
   {"id": 701, "main": "Mist", "description": "mist"},
   {"id": 300, "main": "Drizzle", "description": "light intensity drizzle"}
 ]
}


/* you can find it by id */

console.log(
  dict.weather.find(w => w.id === 300).description
)
```